# Dojo itemfilewritestore delete reference

Tags: dojo

When using the deleteItem function to remove an item from f.ex. a dijit tree, all items with the same id are deleted. Is there any way to only delete one item and not its references?

Answer (score 0):

The dijit tree requires that you have unique identities in your data store to the best of my knowledge.  Perhaps you need to look at the your json data feed and come up with an unique id?

Below is a simple snippet I use to delete items from my tree data store.

```
treeStore.fetchItemByIdentity({
   identity: myUniqueid,
   onItem: function(item) {
      treeStore.deleteItem(item);
   }
});
```

I then call treeStore.Save(); which applies the delete back to the server.  The Tree should be listening to the store for changes and update accordingly.

Comment: It seems that when dragging and dropping an item holding down the ctrl-key or using the pasteItem function with bCopy = true, no new item will be created, however, its new parent will be added to the item's _reverse_ _reference_ _map_. Thus, when deleting the item from the store, both occurrences in the tree will disappear. Is there no way around this problem?